# Find and replace function that will do simple arithmetic?

Tags: linux, svg, sed, replace, linux-mint

I am generating simple SVG diagrams by using sed find and replace on some text input. However, I need a more sophisticated **find and replace operation involving simple math**, to alter certain X and Y values.

E.g. I need to multiply all Y values by a factor of 0.5 or 0.2 or 0.

Because of how I want this to work, it cannot be achieved with a transform operation within the SVG.*

I just need to be able to find, say, all instances of `([0-9.]*)VERT` (in sed speak) and replace with the mathematical result of `\1` multiplied by the constant I choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a simple perl script.  Not sure what determines $factor, but this should at least give you a running start.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
my $factor=0.5;
while(my $line=<>) {
    if ($line =~ /([0-9.]*)VERT/) {
        my $num = $factor * $1;
        $line =~ s/([0-9.]*)VERT/${num}VERT/;
    }
    print $line;
}
```

Usage:  `./scriptname.pl <file_to_process.txt`;

Answer (score 0):

```
 perl -ape 's/[0-9.]*(?=VERT)/$& * .5/e' file
```

hope this works +